# div/javascript mobile scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, joomla

could  somebody help me? I'm using joomla and joomla module BT advanced parallax background. It  creates image gallery.  Problem  is, when  opening this gallery on mobile device, it's not scrolling. I'm tried to add `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` to CSS, but it didn't help me. Also  tried to add  this  to JS file  that creates  parallax animation and gallery content,  and still it doesn't scroll on mobile devices (iOS9). Please, help me guys. I don't know what to do  with it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please add the code you tried?

Comment: Something like this: `var cssOpen = {
     'position': 'absolute',
     'z-index': 99999,
     'width': para_width,
     'height': para_height,
     'top': eTopCurrent,
     'left': eLeftCurrent,
     '-webkit-overflow-scrolling': touch`
from the file - http://zhilyova.com/modules/mod_bt_apb/assets/js/jquery.apb-1.0.0.js

and in css: 
`.parallax-block{
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 9999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
 overflow-y: scroll;
 overflow-x: scroll;
 -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.7);`

Comment: As a tip: You can [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35008380/edit) this code into your question. This will make it easier for answerers to access the information as they don't need to read the comments. If you do so, you highly improve the chance of getting a useful answer

Comment: I'm struggling with this too, I did manage to get it working one time with a -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; addition to my css, but a while later i had changed something and I can't seem to get it working again. Have you tried changing the height attribute to min-height?